# Why are life cycles used as a measure for battery health?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, discharge, capacity, battery-lifespan

I was curious on how the depth of discharge for batteries affects the battery health as I've heard never to let your phone go down to 0%.

I was searching online and every paper I found on this topic seems to compare the depth of discharge to the expected life cycles for a battery.
[image]
**First result on Google***

While this seems helpful as we can see how much use you can get out of the battery as you discharge it to different states of charge, I was wondering why depth of discharge is not also graphed against capacity.

I feel that this would also give a good indicator of the relationship between depth of discharge and battery health as theoretically as you discharge it to lower states of discharge it would reduce the battery's ability to hold a charge. However, I haven't found anyone use capacity as a measure of battery health online.

Could anyone help me understand if I'm missing something here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Think of it as though every time you drain and charge the battery, you loose 0.1% of capacity (that probably high, but arbitrary anyway). If you only discharge it 50%, then you only lose 0.05% of the capacity from that charge cycle.

Comment: Hi! Will you please include a link to the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, I haven't found anyone use capacity as a measure of battery health online.

Actually, it's called the State of Health (SoH) which is the ratio of aged capacity to rated capacity, given as a percentage. For a 1000 mAh battery, if its capacity reduces to 990 mAh after some time, we say the SoH is 99%. Generally, if SoH reaches 80% the battery is considered "dead" (not actually dead but at the end of life as it has lost a significant portion of its performance).

> I was wondering why depth of discharge is not also graphed against capacity.

There are an unlimited number of papers about different experiments and research on batteries. You should be able to find lots of X-vs-SoH graphs for different chemistries and conditions, including SoH vs num of cycles (or cycle number) for different DoD levels.

But since the discharge rate (in C or %C e.g. C/10 or C/1 where C is the capacity) and even the frequency of the discharge-cycle cycle may have an effect on the measurements <sup>(1)</sup>, it might be a very complex/complicated one or even a combination of a number of different graphs.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> For example, for the DoD vs expected life graph in your question (I don't know where you nicked it from, although it says *first results from Google* still we don't know the chemistry and testing conditions), assuming it is generated for a daily cycle, if you discharge your battery to its 60% (DoD = 40%) every day, after 4 years (~1500 cycles/days) the battery will be at its end of life. But if you discharge and charge the battery *every hour* and *4 times a day*, it may not last even less than a year.